# Hiding an internal interface in a "friend" assembly

Tags: c#, .net

I have two assemblies: A and B.  A has InternalsVisibleTo set for B.  I would like to make calls from A to get information that can only be known by a type defined in B in a way that keeps things internal.  I can do this using an internal interface defined in A and implemented explicitly in B.

**Assembly A**

```
  internal interface IHasData
  {
    Data GetData();
  }

  class ClassA 
  {
    DoSomething(IHasData);
  }
```

**Assembly B**

```
  public abstract class ClassB : IHasData
  {
    Data IHasData.GetData() { /** do something internal **/ }
  }
```

The trouble comes when someone references assembly B and derives from ClassB - they get the error: "The type 'AssemblyA.IHasData' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced" even though that type should be invisible to them.  If I look at the public type definition I see what I expect - ClassB with no interfaces implemented.

Why do I get this error?  All of the implementation is in assembly B.  I could use IHasData internally in ClassB and that wouldn't require assembly A to be referenced.  Can someone help me understand what is going on?

Answer (score 3):

It's an interesting find, but it looks like the rules of referencing your references' dependencies when those dependencies are exposed by the reference still apply for explicit interface implementations. I've answered a few questions about this before [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2877952/why-does-my-c-client-that-uses-library-a-need-to-have-a-using-statement-for-libr/2878140#2878140).

A better solution would be to favour composition over inheritance and define an implementation of `IHasData` in an internal class that Assembly B doesn't expose. Something along these lines:

```
  public abstract class ClassB
  {
    class HasData : IHasData
    {
      HasData(ClassB b) {m_b = b;}
      Data IHasData.GetData() { m_b.GetData(); }
    }

    private readonly HasData m_hasData;

    public ClassB() {
      m_hasData = new HasData(this);
    }

    internal Data GetData() { 
      /** do something internal **/ 
    }
  }
```

Comment: +1 for a solid approach.  I would consider adding an internal, implicit operator to convert an instance of `ClassB` to an `IHasData` as well.  Then `ClassB` can still be used internally *as though* it were an `IHasData`.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, that would totally work in a sneaky implicit operator trickery way. In this implementation though, `HasData`'s job is to delegate to ClassB, so those methods might be available anyway. My preferred approach would be to contain the `IHasData` logic as much as possible in `HasData` class and limit its dependency on `ClassB`.

Comment: The issue with this approach is that it is more difficult for assembly A to consume it - though this can be worked around as Mark suggested.  

Do you know if there is a reason for this restriction?

Comment: Nope, you'd need a C# compiler guru to explain this one :))

Answer (score 0):

`ClassB` is publicly visible outside of its assembly, so all of its base types -- classes and interfaces -- must also be publicly visible.  Something that derives from `ClassB` in a different assembly will not be able to see `IHasData` unless you provide an `InternalsVisibleTo` for that assembly as well.

`ClassB` also implements `IHasData` explicitly, which means that the implementation is public by default.